# Pandas - How to drop rows that have timestamps within 6 hours of each other and matching id's

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following sample code/dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df_to_db = pd.DataFrame({
    'or_enter_dt_tm': ['2021-06-06 23:24:00', '2021-06-07 00:52:00', '2021-06-06 23:18:00',
                       '2021-06-01 07:59:00', '2021-07-20 19:24:00', '2021-07-24 15:00:00', '2021-07-20 14:24:00'],
    'or_exit_dt_tm': ['2021-06-06 23:54:00', '2021-06-07 01:58:00', '2021-06-06 23:58:00',
                      '2021-06-01 23:12:00', '2021-07-20 19:25:00', '2021-07-24 19:00:00', '2021-07-20 16:27:00'],
    'id': ['14', '14', '20', '20', '20', '35', '20']
})

# convert to type datetime
df_to_db['or_enter_dt_tm'] = pd.to_datetime(df_to_db['or_enter_dt_tm'])
df_to_db['or_exit_dt_tm'] = pd.to_datetime(df_to_db['or_exit_dt_tm'])


In[2]: df_to_db
Out[2]: 

       or_enter_dt_tm       or_exit_dt_tm  id
0 2021-06-06 23:24:00 2021-06-06 23:54:00  14
1 2021-06-07 00:52:00 2021-06-07 01:58:00  14
2 2021-06-06 23:18:00 2021-06-06 23:58:00  20
3 2021-06-01 07:59:00 2021-06-01 23:12:00  20
4 2021-07-20 19:24:00 2021-07-20 19:25:00  20
5 2021-07-24 15:00:00 2021-07-24 19:00:00  35
6 2021-07-20 14:24:00 2021-07-20 16:27:00  20
```

I want to drop rows where:

1. there is already another or_enter_dt_tm stamp within 6 hours of it AND
2. the id numbers match

Thus for this dataframe I want to drop row 1 and row 6 because they are within 6 hours of row 0 and 4 respectively and the id's match (note: I am fine to drop either of the rows within 6 hours of each other, but only one).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Personally, I would do this in a loop before I convert to a dataframe.  I'll see if I can come up with an example.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this processing before going to pandas.  Pandas is not so good at row-to-row comparisons:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = [
    ['2021-06-06 23:24:00', '2021-06-07 00:52:00', '2021-06-06 23:18:00',
     '2021-06-01 07:59:00', '2021-07-20 19:24:00', '2021-07-24 15:00:00', '2021-07-20 14:24:00'],
    ['2021-06-06 23:54:00', '2021-06-07 01:58:00', '2021-06-06 23:58:00',
     '2021-06-01 23:12:00', '2021-07-20 19:25:00', '2021-07-24 19:00:00', '2021-07-20 16:27:00'],
    ['14', '14', '20', '20', '20', '35', '20']
]

newdata = []
for a,b,c in zip(*data):
    d1 = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(a)
    d2 = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(b)
    if not any( c == row[2] and abs((row[0] - d1).total_seconds()) < 6*60*60 for row in newdata):
        newdata.append( [d1,d2,c] )
print(newdata)

df_to_db = pd.DataFrame( newdata, columns=['or_enter_dt_tm','or_exit_dt_tm','id'])
print(df_to_db)
```

Output:

```
       or_enter_dt_tm       or_exit_dt_tm  id
0 2021-06-06 23:24:00 2021-06-06 23:54:00  14
1 2021-06-06 23:18:00 2021-06-06 23:58:00  20
2 2021-06-01 07:59:00 2021-06-01 23:12:00  20
3 2021-07-20 19:24:00 2021-07-20 19:25:00  20
4 2021-07-24 15:00:00 2021-07-24 19:00:00  35
```